# Imputation of missing value with median

Tags: python

I want to impute a column of a dataframe called  Bare Nuclei with a median and I got this error 
('must be str, not int', 'occurred at index Bare Nuclei') 
the following code represents the unique value of the column data['Bare Nuclei]

```
data['Bare Nuclei'].unique()
array(['1', '10', '2', '4', '3', '9', '7', '?', '5', '8', '6'],
      dtype=object)
```

Then, I tried to replace `?` with `nan` and then impute `nan` with median but I got the above error

```
data['Bare Nuclei'] = data['Bare Nuclei'].replace('?',np.nan)
#data['Bare Nuclei'].fillna()
data.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()),axis=0)
```

To check with the data is available in this link https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/

Answer (score 1):

The error you got is because the values stored in the `'Bare Nuclei'` column are stored as strings, but the `mean()` function requires numbers. You can see that they are strings in the result of your call to `.unique()`.

After replacing the `'?'` characters, you can convert the series to numbers using `.astype(float)`:

```
data['Bare Nuclei'] = data['Bare Nuclei'].replace('?',np.nan)
data['Bare Nuclei'] = data['Bare Nuclei'].astype(float).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Comment: I tried it and i got error 'float' object has no attribute 'fillna'

Answer (score 0):

this is the Correction and it works

```
data['Bare Nuclei'] = data['Bare Nuclei'].replace('?',np.nan).astype(float)
data['Bare Nuclei'] = data['Bare Nuclei'].fillna((data['Bare Nuclei'].median()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this function if you want to use medians and fill in a little more detailed and realistic.

````
def groupby_median_imputer(data,features_array,*args):
  #unlimited groups
  from tqdm import tqdm
  print("The numbers of remaining missing values that columns have:")
  for i in tqdm(features_array):
    data[i] = data.groupby([*args])[i].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median()))
    print( i + " : " + data[i].isnull().sum().astype(str)) ```
````